# WiFi adapter disappears when I connect to wired network

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet, hot-spot

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, but I had this problem on Debian and Widows 7 too.

I want to use my computer as hotspot while it's connected to LAN, but as soon as I connect the ethernet cable, WiFi is disabled and it says "No WiFi adapter found".

I think I have only one network adapter and it switches between wired and wireless, but I can't find a way to not make it do this. Is there a way?

Comment: Is there an option in BIOS to disable wifi when Ethernet is used?

Comment: Welcome to [Ubuntu.se] **:-)** Please [edit] your answer and provide above requested details as now it's **unclear what you're asking...  :-(**